# How to apply the scale of a specific object through a python script?

Tags: python, transforms

I tried

```
 bpy.data.objects['Cube_1'].transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)
```

but it gives this error *'Object' object has no attribute 'transform_apply'*

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)
```

it only works if the object is selected in the viewport which is not useful for my case since I intend to automate this task for specific objects

Comment: for these specific objects, can you not individually automate the selection them and then apply the transform for the active selected object? Using 'obj.select_set(True)' before the transform apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a loop over all the objects of interest which should be in your `my_specific_objects_list` and call `select_set(True)` on them and then call `bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)`. I don't see what the problem with this is. It is still all automated unless you can give us a specific scenario why this is not feasible in your case.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
my_specific_objects_list = bpy.data.objects

for o in my_specific_objects_list:
    o.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)
```

Comment: thank you, since I don't have that many objects in the scene  your method worked great.

Answer (score 7):

**To apply all transforms** without using operators:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Matrix

mat = C.object.matrix_local
C.object.data.transform(mat)
C.object.matrix_local = Matrix()
# the above line is equivalent to:
# C.object.location = 0, 0, 0
# C.object.rotation_euler = 0, 0, 0
# C.object.scale = 1, 1, 1
```

Since the order of decomposed Matrix transformations is such that scale is applied first, **if you want to only apply scale** you can just take the scale component and apply it and set the scale to the default:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Matrix

mat = C.object.matrix_local
location, rotation, scale = mat.decompose()
mat_scale = Matrix.LocRotScale(None, None, scale)
C.object.data.transform(mat_scale)
C.object.scale = 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: This also worked, thank you so much for taking the time.